# Changing entity expansion limit in Java Xerces DocumentBuilder

Tags: java, xml, xerces

When creating a `DocumentBuilder` using  `Xerces`  java library, can we set our own `Entity Expansion Limit` ? By default the limit is set to `100,000` and I could not find a way to change this value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the System property `entityExpansionLimit`.

```
-DentityExpansionLimit=1234
```

Comment: I have tried setting the system property like you mentioned. But still, the builder seems to be using the default in `DEFAULT_ENTITY_EXPANSION_LIMIT` set in `org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager`.